# Unity Material constructor not applying Shader

Tags: unity

I am proceedurally generating a generic game object and trying to make it transparent using the default diffuse transparency shader.

```
meshRenderer.materials[0]=new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse"));
meshRenderer.materials[0].color = new Color(0f,1f,0f,0.05f);
```

Just seems to make it Default-Diffuse, but if I do this

```
meshRenderer.materials[0]=new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse"));
meshRenderer.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");
meshRenderer.materials[0].color = new Color(0f,1f,0f,0.05f);
```

It works just fine and I get transparency.  The Material constructor looks like it takes the exact same shader, but it doesnt seem to be applying.  Why?  I am already explicitly inluding the shader in the project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change material of your gameObject using:

```
renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse"));
renderer.material.color = new Color(0f,1f,0f,0.05f);
```

which seems to work fine. I was searching unity3d forums and found [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/32250/meshrenderermaterials.html) which also seems to work fine. Here's the code for the same:

```
var meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
var mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse"));
mat.color = new Color(0f,1f,0f,0.05f);
var matArray = new Material[]{mat};
meshRenderer.materials = matArray;
```